# Verify inline code when building ASP.NET MVC2 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, build

Is there some setting that can be turned on in Visual Studio 2010 to make it compile/verify the inline code in my MVC2 views when I hit build? Much like what happens when I open a view.